# xml files in android : How to design them and access in java code

Tags: android

How to edit xml files within layout directory in android. And how can I use controls (defined in xml file) in my java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, double click on the XML file, it will be opened in the editing pan at the right side. You can edit it in either Graphical Layout or XML by clicking on the tabs below.

Update: You can use the controls (or widgets) defined in XML file in Java code in the following way. Say, you've defined an EditText element with `android:id="@+id/textFirstName"`, you can access this in code like this,

```
EditText textFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
textFirstName.setText("Bugatti");
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html this link might be an add on

Comment: What about setContentView. If I want to design layout in xml and use in java code, how it will be. I know setContentView(R.layer.main) format I can use( which was on a tutorial site) but in xml file there no any any declaration for main.

Comment: @Pankaj: The identifier you use with setContentView() is the name of XML file. It is not something stored or declared in XML. So, if you've defined your layout in a file named, Navigation.xml, you can load it like this, setContentView( R.layout.Navigation ); (And its R.layout not R.layer).